# Adding a new project type to Projectile Mode

Tags: projectile

I would like Projectile Mode to recognize other projects besides the default ones (GIT, Maven, etc.) The `README.md` describes how to customize project root files, however it doesn't explain how Projectile learns what files belong to a project once it has found a project root file.  Therefore, what are the steps needed to configure a custom project root file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have `projectile-indexing-method` set to 'alien' (the
default except for Windows), if the VCS isn't recognized, projectile
will call `projectile-generic-command`, which is "find . -type f
-print0" by default. If you want to take a closer look,
`projectile-get-ext-command` is the function that decides to what to
call.

I don't think there's any easy way to add a custom project type, but for an example of what you'd need to add, you can follow [this commit](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/commit/8576b3a776f7e8554d5bf3865f03d9a1de23951e) that added support for fossil.

---

It's probably wrong for me to use the term 'project type' above since
projectile has a `projectile-project-type` that determines a project
type that is unrelated to the VCS used (django, python, rails,...). This
information is only used for setting the test and compilation commands.
As described above, it is the VCS (or lack of one) that determines how
project files are collected.

Comment: Thank you.  However, it seems that `projectile-get-ext-command` is meant for VCS files, albeit I think that it could be bent to other uses.  Do you have any idea about how to do a similar thing with the kind of files listed in `projectile-project-root-files`?

Comment: Apparently, with VCS, Projectile will recognize only files under source control; but with other kind of projects, Projectile will take all the files inside the directory as project files.  Right?

Comment: Yes, if there's not a recognized VCS (and `projectile-indexing-method`
is 'alien'), `projectile-generic-command` will be used, which by default
finds all files. For VCS projects, projectile will use
`projectile-VCS-command`. This doesn't necessarily mean that the file is
under source control. For example, `projectile-git-command` includes
untracked files.

Comment: If you want to treat a directory as a project, simply create an empty `.projectile` there. You can exclude files/directories you don't want by specifying it in `.projectile` file. See [Ignoring Files](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile#ignoring-files).

Comment: @TuDo: I don't want to treat a directory as a project.  I want Projectile to recognize as project files those files that are specified inside a special file (which is not `.projectile`).  I know how to parse that special file, but I don't know how to pass the file list to Projectile.

Comment: @KyleMeyer: Thanks for the clarification.  Therefore I think that the current documentation string of `projectile-get-ext-command` misleads, because it talks explicitly of VCS, but in reality the function is generic.